# Processing values of a collection in parallel using ReactiveExtensions

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I am new to Rx. According to documentation, it looks like it is possible to run OnNext handler for each value in parallel, on different threads. I just need to ObserveOn appropriate scheduler implementation.

But this simple code runs synchronously:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, object> {{1, null}, {5, null}, {6, null}};

dict.ToObservable()
  .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Default)
  .Subscribe(kv => {
     Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}, key {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, kv.Key);
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
  });
```

On the screen I see the same thread Id for each iteration. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rx defines a grammar that specifically prohibits OnNext from overlapping *from the standpoint of any given Observer*. It is possible that *multiple* subscribers to a stream can be called in parallel (but that depends on the implementer of the Rx operator).

Here we have two subscribers that handle OnNext at different rates from the same stream:

```
void Main()
{
    var stream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));    

    var sub1 = stream.Subscribe(x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Sub1 handler start: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Sub1 handler end");
    });

    var sub2 = stream.Subscribe(x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Sub2 handler start: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Sub2 handler end");
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here is the output, see how Sub2 is racing ahead of Sub1, and each is on their own thread.

```
Sub2 handler start: 18
Sub1 handler start: 12
Sub2 handler end
Sub2 handler start: 18
Sub2 handler end
Sub2 handler start: 18
Sub1 handler end
Sub1 handler start: 12
Sub2 handler end
Sub2 handler start: 18
Sub2 handler end
Sub1 handler end
Sub2 handler start: 18
Sub1 handler start: 12
```

Note that there's nothing to say that each subscription get's it's own thread - that's down to how the scheduler and operator are implemented. As long as they conform to the Rx grammar of **OnNext* (OnError | OnCompleted)** anything goes.

For your particular scenario, I would look into [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) / TPL - it feels like a better fit than Rx.

By the way, Lee Campbell's [www.introtorx.com](http://www.introtorx.com) is a good resource if you are just starting out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what should I do if my OnNext handler is really long-running? In real world scenario, other threads will add some values to the 'dict' object in runtime. Maybe it's better to implement producer/consumer pattern using Queue + Monitor? Hm.

Comment: [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220689/why-each-observation-delegate-runs-on-a-new-thread?rq=1) got desired behavior and is trying to figure out, how :-)

Comment: James, you made my day. Now I cleanly understand what is going on. Rx protects OnNext handlers from overlapping (inside given Observer). Schedulers are used just to schedule next OnNext call, after previous one is finished.

Comment: As you say values could be added to your dictionary over time, perhaps a Subject would work better. You can run a yourSubject.SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(*async function here*)) to run calculations in parallel and get a stream of results - and it will continue to work as items are added to the Subject.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks!