# Why is Rx.Net OnNext handler invoked on the same thread, ignoring the scheduler provided

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I'm stuck with strange behaviour of RX.Net schedulers (or have totally wrong understanding of the concept).

There is one thread, which produces events, and I want to handle those events concurrently, on the thread pool. But all of the handlers are invoked on the same thread. Seems, that sheduler set with `ObserveOn()`, is ignored.

Here is small scenario to reproduce:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Observable
        .Create<int>(observer => Task.Run(() => Generate(observer)))
        .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(i =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i));

            Console.WriteLine(
               "Got {0} on thread \t{1}",
                i,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Generate(IObserver<int> observer)
{
    var i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Generated {0} on thread \t{1}",
            i,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        observer.OnNext(i++);
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Generated 0 on thread   10
Got 0 on thread         12
Generated 1 on thread   10
Generated 2 on thread   10
Got 1 on thread         12
Generated 3 on thread   10
Got 2 on thread         12
Generated 4 on thread   10
Generated 5 on thread   10
Generated 6 on thread   10
Got 3 on thread         12
Generated 7 on thread   10
Generated 8 on thread   10
Generated 9 on thread   10
Generated 10 on thread  10
Got 4 on thread         12
```

Comment: Does this maybe help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220689/why-each-observation-delegate-runs-on-a-new-thread (Although the OP there seems to be having the opposite problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong concept of how Rx works.

There is a contract of behaviour that says that values produced by observables are serialized. You should always expect the values to be returned one after another from an observable and that each `.OnNext(...)` handler will complete before the next value is handled.

You can, however, make observables process data in parallel using `.SelectMany(...)`.

First up though, you have created a `Generate` method. You don't need to. It's always a very good idea to use built-in operators. They are fully tested so you should use them instead. There happens to be a `Observable.Generate` method that you should use. To replicate your function you would do this:

```
Observable.Generate(0, i => true, i => i + 1, i => i, TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
```

So now it because quite easy to replicate the code that you have:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Generate(
        0,
        i => true,
        i => i + 1,
        i => i,
        TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
    from id in Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); /* simulated processing - should never do this otherwise */
        return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    })
    select new { n, id };
```

If I handle that like this:

```
using (var subscription =
    query
        .Take(20)
        .Subscribe(x =>
            Console.WriteLine("Processed {0} on thread {1} and handled on {2}",
                x.n.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' '),
                x.id.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' '),
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' '))))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get these results:

```
Processed  4 on thread 23 and handled on 23
Processed  2 on thread 20 and handled on 20
Processed  0 on thread 22 and handled on 22
Processed  6 on thread 17 and handled on 17
Processed  7 on thread 21 and handled on 21
Processed  3 on thread 19 and handled on 19
Processed  5 on thread 15 and handled on 15
Processed  1 on thread 24 and handled on 24
Processed  8 on thread 14 and handled on 14
Processed 12 on thread 17 and handled on 17
Processed  9 on thread 23 and handled on 23
Processed 14 on thread 19 and handled on 19
Processed 16 on thread 24 and handled on 24
Processed 10 on thread 20 and handled on 20
Processed 11 on thread 22 and handled on 22
Processed 15 on thread 15 and handled on 15
Processed 13 on thread 21 and handled on 21
Processed 17 on thread 13 and handled on 13
Processed 18 on thread 14 and handled on 14
Processed 19 on thread 17 and handled on 17
```

Notice how the values produced from the `Observable.Generate` are out of order? That's the parallel processing in action.

Comment: Thanks, it makes some sense after a while. But now it looks rather weird, that the main work is done as a side effect of the map function.
`source.SelectMany(m => Observable.Start(() => OnMessage(m))).Subscribe(_ => { }, OnError);`


_And, of course, all the `Thread.Sleep` invocations, were used just as a simulation. And generation function was written with goal to replicate production code, where one thread is sitting and waiting for messages from external source, which are dispatched with use of RX then._